# Field extension-Why does this hold?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

$K\leq E$ a field extension, $a\in E$ is algebraic over $K$.

Could you explain me why the following holds??

$$K\leq K(a^2)\leq K(a)$$

Comment: Basically this says that "any field that contains $a$ and $K$ will also contain $a^2$". So it looks like a consequence of the fact that a field is closed under multiplication.

Comment: In general, can you say what $K(b)$ means when $b \in E$?

Comment: @user180040 Sorry, somehow I was tired and thought I was reading answer comments.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ok... Thank you very much!!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well by definition $K \leq K(a^2)$.
Then since $a^2 \in K(a)$ ($K(a)$ is closed under multiplication), $K(a^2) \leq K(a)$.

Comment: Ok... Thank you very much!!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

$K\leq K(a^2)$ and $K\leq K(a^2)$ must be clear to you. only thing to see here is that $K(a^2)\leq K(a)$ and if you prove $a^2 \in K(a)$ you are done, right? That is simply closure.

Comment: Ok... Thank you very much!!! :-)